# Return current $this in a class

Tags: php, class

I have this class

```
<?php
class testing {
    public $vars;
    public function vars($str) {
        $this->vars = $str;
        return $this;
    }
}
?>
```

and this code

```
$testing = new testing();
var_dump($testing);
$dd = $testing->vars('hello');
$ee = $testing->vars('bye');
var_dump($dd);
var_dump($testing);
die;
```

the variable $testing->vars of $dd should be 'hello', but it is 'bye' instead.

So how to make that $ee does not affect $dd? I mean, return an object with all variables for each function.

Sorry for my bad english, and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An object is always passed around as reference. If you want two separate disjoint objects, you need to explicitly [`clone`](http://php.net/clone) it.

Answer (score 0):

what happens is that these returning reference of the object and not a value. then either have to if you need to clone the object, but if you need only the values ​​that have:

```
    class testing {
    private $vars;
    public function vars($str) {
        $this->vars = $str;
        return  $this->vars;
    }
  } 
    $testing = new testing();
    var_dump($testing);
    $dd = $testing->vars('hello');
    $ee = $testing->vars('bye');
    var_dump($dd);
    var_dump($ee);
    var_dump($testing);
     die;
```